# Execute a bash script with arguments in Ansible

Tags: bash, ansible, slack

I am new to Ansible. I have a bash script which has three arguments to be passed. I have to run this bash script on the remote server from Ansible.

Basically, I want to  declare the hostname, duration and the comment fields as arguments while executing the Ansible command. I don't want to edit the file, as I am doing it from a Slack channel.

```
- hosts: nagiosserver

  tasks:
   - name: Executing a script
     command: sh /home/aravind/downtime.sh {hostname} {duration} {comments}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow could you please edit and add your sh file content

Answer (score 5):

If you're executing ansible via `ansible-playbook myplay.yml`, you can pass additional variables via `-e varname=varvalue`. A lazy fix would be to run with

```
ansible-playbook myplay.yml -e my_hostname=foo -e my_duration=bar -e my_comments=foobar
```

But you should consider that the hostname is already defined in your inventory or gathered facts.

So you could update your playbook to use these additional variables using

```
- hosts: nagiosserver

  tasks:
    - name: Executing a script
    - command: "sh /home/aravind/downtime.sh {{my_hostname}} {{my_duration}} {{my_comments}}"
```